# How to play audio(in generator loop) with Pyglet?

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, pyglet

Version of pyglet - 1.4.2.
 Python - 3.6.6
Ubuntu - 18.04

#### Code example:

```
import pyglet
import time

pyglet.options['audio'] = ('openal', 'pulse', 'directsound', 'silent')
source = pyglet.media.StaticSource(pyglet.media.load('explosion.wav'))

def my_playlist():
    while True:
        print(time.time())
        print(1)
        yield source


player = pyglet.media.Player()
player.queue(my_playlist())
player.play()

pyglet.app.run()
```

Code was writed based on [documentation](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/programming_guide/media.html#controlling-playback):

#### Logs in console:

```
1566296930.8165386  # played once
1
1566296931.529639  # won't play
1
1566296931.5301056  # won't play and etc.
1
1566296931.5304687
1
1566296931.5309348
1
```

#### Expected result:

Audio should play in loop with sounds which is returned from generator.

#### Current result:

Audio is played once.

#### Question:

What I did wrong here and how to achive expected result?

Comment: As I found out reason was in corrupted `.wav` file and Ubuntu OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you're trying to accomplish something more, but if all you need from your loop is to loop sound, you shouldn't actually use a `loop` of any kind. Instead, use the designated [EOS_LOOP](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/pyglet-1.2-maintenance/api/pyglet/media/pyglet.media.Player.html#pyglet.media.Player.EOS_LOOP) flag/trigger.

```
import pyglet
import time

pyglet.options['audio'] = ('openal', 'pulse', 'directsound', 'silent')
source = pyglet.media.StaticSource(pyglet.media.load('explosion.wav'))

player = pyglet.media.Player()
player.queue(source)
player.EOS_LOOP = 'loop'
player.play()

pyglet.app.run()
```

And since it's deprecated, you should move away to using the [SourceGroup](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/pyglet-1.2-maintenance/api/pyglet/media/pyglet.media.SourceGroup.html#attributes) with the loop flag set.

Comment: your example is not working for me too. It plays sound once and then it's silent. I'm not trying to accomplish anything not from documentation. `pyglet` provide documentation, where sound `yield main_theme` should be played untill game `while game_is_running()`. I thought, that soundtrack `main_theme` should be repeated until statement `game_is_running()` is `True`. So I just took this example and tried to implement such thing.

Comment: 1 sound in loop is just an example, generator could `yield` many other sounds, but as I understand - sound should be able to be repeated.

Comment: I also tried to make it working and I have one file which never loop - it plays only once if it is yielded or when I use `player.loop = True`. Other files loop with `player.loop = True` or when they are `yielded`. This strange file loops only if there is another file yielded in function.

Comment: I took working file and after cutting it to (more or less) 1second it stoped looping.

Comment: I'll have a look at it tonight. Not sure why that isn't working. @YuriyLeonov what version of Pyglet and Python are you running?

Comment: @Torxed Mentioned in top of question: `pyglet - 1.4.2.` and `python 3.6` (3.6.6 explicit version)

Comment: documentation for pyglet, which was used (also metioned as link) - https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/programming_guide/media.html#controlling-playback

Comment: @Torxed issue reprodused only on Ubuntu(18.04), On Windows 10 my code works well. So I'll create corresponding ticket in pyglet repository